# Conveying 'squaring both sides'

Tags: traduction, anglais, mathématiques

[image]

To prove this statement, I want to say

> Squaring both sides of x+y+z=0, we get...

I'm thinking about

> En prenant les carrés de deux membres de l'équation, on obtient...

but I'm wondering if there are better formulations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ta proposition est correcte. On peut aussi dire (je commence par la formulation qui me vient en premier à l'esprit)

> En élevant les deux côtés au carré, on obtient …

ou

> En élevant au carré, on obtient …

ou

> En prenant le carré des deux côtés, on obtient …

ou encore « En passant au carré [des deux côtés], on obtient … », qui me paraît moins naturel, mais par contre j'utiliserais « en passant à l'inverse » indifféremment avec « en prenant l'inverse ».

Comment: On a aussi « mettre au carré » qui est moins correcte qu'élever mais qu'on entend souvent à l'oral